# Pandas GroupBy with two columns but count on both fields / agg() output

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

> Evening All,
>
> My code acomplishes what I need it to do but I am curious as to why it
>   works.

```
dft2 = pd.DataFrame(
                        np.array([
                                    ['1','A','WW'], ['1','B','XX'], ['3','A','LL'], ['1','D','ZZ'],['2','A','LL'],['3','E','LL']
                                ]), columns=['channel','state', 'rbc_security_type1']
                  )
display(dft2)


    channel state   rbc_security_type1
0   1         A          WW
1   1         B          XX
2   3         A          LL
3   1         D          ZZ
4   2         A          LL
5   3         E          LL

d = {
        ('state',np.size),
        ('rbc_security_type1',np.size)   
    }

dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['state'].agg(d).reset_index() 
dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['rbc_security_type1'].agg(d).reset_index() 

dft2_Grp = dft2_Grp.rename(columns={'state':'State_Count', 'rbc_security_type1':'rbc_security_type1_Count'}, level=0) # rename the column header in the groupby
display(dft2_Grp)
```

> Now both these aggregations yield the same output and I'd like to know why?

```
dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['state'].agg(d).reset_index() 
dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['rbc_security_type1'].agg(d).reset_index() 


        channel State_Count rbc_security_type1_Count
    0   1           3               3
    1   2           1               1
    2   3           2               2
```

> What exactly is happenning when we .groupby('channel')[column].agg(d)
>   when we are applying counts on multiple columns? The aggregation of d
>   ('state',np.size), ('rbc_security_type1',np.size) makes sense to me
>   but why is there a need to add only one [column] when the agg(d)
>   already has both columns I want to count on in it? Why are both
>   columns not required?
>
> If I ommit the [], which I thought made sense,  and use the following
>   command I get the output:

```
dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel').agg(d).reset_index(). The output follows:
channel     State_Count                 rbc_security_type1_Count
            state   rbc_security_type1  state   rbc_security_type1
0   1       3           3               3           3
1   2       1           1               1           1
2   3       2           2               2           2
```

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get same output, because call same function twice and function return count of values per groups.

```
d = {
        ('state',np.size),
        ('rbc_security_type1',np.size)   
    }

dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['state'].agg(d).reset_index()
```

For column `state` per groups by `channel` return 2 new columns called `state` and `rbc_security_type1` with same aggreagte function `np.size`.

---

```
dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['rbc_security_type1'].agg(d).reset_index()
```

For column `rbc_security_type1` per groups by `channel` return 2 new columns called `state` and `rbc_security_type1` with same aggreagte function `np.size`.

---

So better is use it something like:

```
d = {
        ('a',np.size),
        ('b','first')   
    }

dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel')['state'].agg(d).reset_index() 
print(dft2_Grp)
  channel  a  b
0       1  3  A
1       2  1  A
2       3  2  A
```

For columnn `state` create new columns by different functions - `first` return first value per group.

---

```
d = {
        'state': np.size,
        'rbc_security_type1':np.size
    }

dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel').agg(d).reset_index() 
print(dft2_Grp)
  channel  state  rbc_security_type1
0       1      3                   3
1       2      1                   1
2       3      2                   2
```

For aggregate by dictionary without tuples (more common) are columns with aggreate function define in `dictionary` - so for `state` is define function `np.size` and for `rbc_security_type1` same:

---

```
d = {
        ('a',np.size),
        ('b',np.size)   
    }

dft2_Grp = dft2.groupby('channel').agg(d).reset_index() 
print(dft2_Grp)
  channel state    rbc_security_type1   
              b  a                  b  a
0       1     3  3                  3  3
1       2     1  1                  1  1
2       3     2  2                  2  2
```

This means for all columns are used all functions in dictionary - here double `np.size` and return `MultiIndex` in columns for distingush input columns.